# JQuery unable to perform hover events on dynamically added input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been tying to perform hover operation on dynamically added input fields.

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "input", "hover", function(event) {
    alert("ok");
});
```

Also tried using but works only for static fields.

```
 $('input').hover(
    function(event) {
        alert("bring tooltip");
    }, 

    function(event) {
        if (hasfocus) {
            alert("Keep the tooltip");
        }
    }
);
```

Need suggestions.Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Botimoo I have tried "live" but error in console saying "live is not a function"

Comment: Both `live` and `delegate` are deprecated, you should be using `on`

Comment: Just as the post I linked above and everyone here says: use `.on()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
Secondly, you shouldn't be using a `hover` event.
Thirdly, delegate to the `document`, not the `body`, or preferable just to the closest static parent element.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter : function() {

    },
    mouseleave : function() {
        if ( this === document.activeElement ) {
            // has focus
        }
    }
}, 'input');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $("input").on("hover",function(event){
    alert("bring tooltip");
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.